# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object, using array.includes

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the following code throws a "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

```
const array = [1, 2];

[3, 4].every(array.includes);
```

Comment: `array.includes` will return a function. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think he wants array.includes to return a function

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind it

```
const array = [1, 2];

const r1 = [1, 2].every(array.includes.bind(array));
const r2 = [3, 4].every(array.includes.bind(array));
```

--- edit

The above is incorrect, because the `every` callback takes the index of the current item as the second parameter, but `array.includes` takes the fromIndex as the second parameter. Thanks to Nina Scholz in the comments.

What you want is

```
[1,2].every(n => arr.includes(n));
```

Comment: looks good, but does not work for items in defferent order, because `includes` has a second parameter *fromIndex*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to `.every()` which takes the current element as parameter:

```
[3, 4].every(element => array.includes(element));
```

---

```js
const array = [1, 2];

console.log(
    [3, 4].every(element => array.includes(element))
);

console.log(
    [1, 2].every(element => array.includes(element))
);
```